# How can I read two integers on single line in MASM (with Irvine lib)?

Tags: assembly, masm

```
    Include Irvine32.inc

    .data
    prompt BYTE "Input two integers: ", 0
    intA DWORD ?
    intB DWORD ?

    .code
    MAIN PROC
    mov edx, OFFSEt prompt
    call WriteString
    call ReadDec
    mov intA, eax

call ReadDec
mov intB, eax

add eax, intA
call WriteDec

exit
MAIN ENDP
END MAIN
```

When I input "1 -> enter -> 2" in order, the program works well.
But when I input "1 -> space bar -> 2 -> enter" in order, the program outputs 1
How can i fix it?

Comment: Depends on what library functions you have available. In the worst case, you need to read a string, split and convert it yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ReadDec docs](http://programming.msjc.edu/asm/help/index.html?page=source%2Firvinelib%2Freaddec.htm)

> Reads a 32-bit unsigned decimal integer from standard input, stopping
>   when the Enter key is pressed.    All valid digits occurring before a
>   non-numeric character are converted to the integer value.    Leading
>   spaces are ignored.

So entering `"1 2<enter>"` should return integer value `1`, per the definition of `ReadDec`.

If you want to process input like that, you will have to read it as string, parse it into separate small strings (per number) on your own, and then you can call Irvine lib `ParseDecimal32` (or `ParseInteger32`), or create your own string->number conversion.

Comment: Eventually, if this is not exercise, probably best solution is to include one of the clib implementation and call `sscanf` (pick one of the safer variants). Or actually write the whole SW in C++. Doing your own `scanf/printf` with the same features, quality, performance and correctness, would take many hours of programming (more like days or weeks, than hours), so using the clib is obvious solution.